# Using NEXT clause to set periodic materilized view refresh in oracle and verifying refresh

Tags: oracle, materialized-view, oracle-apex

I am not able to find the right documentation on setting specific timings for materialized view refresh for oracle. I read up the documentation and some examples there, however there is no definite documentation on using NEXT clause. What would I do to set up refresh every day at 8am and 8pm for example? How would I achieve refresh 3 times a day?

Here's what I am using in my case. I understand this will start refresh at 7am tomorrow and next every 12 hours?

```
alter materialized view MY_VIEW
refresh fast
start with (sysdate+1) + 7/24
next trunc(sysdate) + ((trunc(to_char(sysdate,'HH24')/12)*12)+12)/24
```

I also want to know if there is a way to know how to verify if the materialized view was refreshed once the timings are set.

Update:
I tried to refresh my MV every hour, which didi not work. I am wondering why is that. Here's what I used:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW  "MYVIEW"
  ORGANIZATION HEAP PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "APEX_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
  BUILD IMMEDIATE
  USING INDEX 
  REFRESH FAST ON DEMAND START WITH sysdate+0 NEXT sysdate+1/24
  USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT
  USING ENFORCED CONSTRAINTS DISABLE QUERY REWRITE
  AS select *
from <mydblinktable>
```

Comment: `sysdate + 0.5` should do the same. 0.5 days = 12 hours. But be aware, time is calculated after job is finished, so refresh time will shift forwards by time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use `DBMS_SCHEDULER` instead, with a job for each refresh. It's then easier to manage, and view previous executions.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE REFRESH_MY_VIEW
AS
BEGIN
    DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH('MY_VIEW');
END;
/
```

Refresh at 8am every day:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
    (
    job_name            => 'REFRESH_MY_VIEW',
    job_type            => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action          => 'REFRESH_MY_VIEW',
    number_of_arguments => 0,
    start_date          => SYSTIMESTAMP, 
    repeat_interval => 'freq=daily; byhour=8; byminute=0; bysecond=0;',
    end_date            => NULL,
    enabled             => TRUE,
    auto_drop           => FALSE,
    comments            => 'Refreshes MY_VIEW at 8am'
    );
END;
/
```

Refresh at 8pm every day:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB
    (
    job_name            => 'REFRESH_MY_VIEW',
    job_type            => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action          => 'REFRESH_MY_VIEW',
    number_of_arguments => 0,
    start_date          => SYSTIMESTAMP, 
    repeat_interval => 'freq=daily; byhour=20; byminute=0; bysecond=0;',
    end_date            => NULL,
    enabled             => TRUE,
    auto_drop           => FALSE,
    comments            => 'Refreshes MY_VIEW at 8pm'
    );
END;
/
```

The `*_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG` and `*_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS` data dictionary views provide all the information you need to track what executed, when, and if any errors occurred. Documentation link [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17120/scheduse008.htm#insertedID1).

As pointed out in a comment, you can add multiple `by hour` clauses, comma-separated, as follows: `repeat_interval => 'freq=daily; byhour=8,20; byminute=0; bysecond=0;'`

Comment: Okay, this sounds like a good option too. Any particular reason why you would prefer DBMS Scheduler instead of auto-refresh on materialized views? One more thing, after posting this question, I tried refreshing my view every hour, which did not working. I will surely try dbms scheduler, but I am trying to understand why my MV auto-refresh did not work. I am updating my question with my code.

Comment: @SejalParikh refresh groups are best for 1 thing: data consistency between related mviews.  An implicit commit is performed before/after DBMS_MVIEW.REFRESH is called, so data inconsistency can come into play if you have multiple mviews with PK/FK relationships.  If you do have that need, then refresh groups solves that problem since the entire group is atomic.  Barring that, dbms_scheduler is easier to use, more versatile, more logging; Overall, a better approach to mview refreshes.  I've even had refresh groups stop refreshing for no apparent reason... a simple re-call solves those hiccups.

Comment: @SejalParikh Oh, using the NEXT clause automatically creates a refresh group with the same name as the mview to perform the mview refresh on the NEXT schedule, so if you are confused when I say "refresh group", we are still talking about the same thing...

Comment: You need only one schedule: `repeat_interval => 'freq=daily; byhour=8,20; byminute=0; bysecond=0;'`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit I didn't know you could do that, thanks

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: Yes that's what I did. I also scheduled another one for 'freq=freq=MINUTELY; interval=120' - that would schedule for every 2 hours from start time.

Comment: Yes, or `freq=hourly,interval=2` does the same